# How can I fix the Delphi error 'Cannot assign to a read-only property' in my web browser code?

Tags: browser

I have this error in Delphi code and I don't know how to fix it  [Error] Unit1.pas(47): Cannot assign to a read-only property.
I've tried a lot but so far nothing has worked for me.

```
   unit Unit1;

     interface

     uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, ComCtrls, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Menus;

   type
     TForm1 = class(TForm)
       pgc1: TPageControl;
       ts1: TTabSheet;
          wb1: TWebBrowser;
          btn5: TButton;
          procedure btn5Click(Sender: TObject);
        private
          { Private declarations }
        public
          { Public declarations }
        end;

      var
        Form1: TForm1;
        NewSheet: TTabSheetя;
      implementation

      {$R *.dfm}

      procedure TForm1.btn5Click(Sender: TObject);
      var
        NewSheet: TTabSheet;
        wb2: TWebBrowser;
      begin
        NewSheet := TTabSheet.Create(pgc1);
        NewSheet.PageControl := pgc1;
        NewSheet.Caption := 'New tab';

        wb2 := TWebBrowser.Create(Self);

         wb2.Parent := NewSheet;    //mistic

        wb2.Align := alClient;
        wb2.Navigate('http://www.google.com');
      end;
      end.
```

this error pops up when trying to add a wb2 component to NewSheet
I am building a Delphi web browser and wanted to add tabs on button click

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using this code:

```
TWinControl(wb2).Parent:=newSheet;
```